# NUnit ITestRunner can not find test dll - Win32Exception : The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: nunit

Using NUnit doc tutorial https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit-engine/Getting-Started.html to run test using ITestRunner I found a problem to actully run the tests because of error "The system cannot find the file specified"

we are using .net 4.6.1

`

```
<command-line><![CDATA[C:\YYY\code\XXXXautotests\XXXXAutoTests\Build\TestAutomation.ApiTest.exe]]></command-line><test-suite type="Assembly" id="0" name="TestAutomation.ApiTest.dll" fullname="C:\YYY\code\XXXXautotests\XXXXAutoTests\TestAutomation.ApiTest\obj\Debug\TestAutomation.ApiTest.dll" runstate="NotRunnable" testcasecount="1" result="Failed" label="Error" start-time="2022-10-27 13:34:29Z" end-time="2022-10-27 13:34:29Z" duration="0.001" total="1" passed="0" failed="1" inconclusive="0" skipped="0" asserts="0"><failure><message><![CDATA[System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : The system cannot find the file specified]]></message><stack-trace><![CDATA[--Win32Exception
The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at NUnit.Engine.Services.TestAgency.GetAgent(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Engine.Runners.ProcessRunner.CreateAgentAndRunnerIfNeeded()
   at NUnit.Engine.Runners.ProcessRunner.RunTests(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)
]]></stack-trace></failure></test-suite>
```

`

I tried different paths:

- C:\YYY\code\XXXXautotests\XXXXAutoTests\TestAutomation.ApiTest\obj\Debug\TestAutomation.ApiTest.dll
- C:\YYY\code\XXXXautotests\XXXXAutoTests\Build\TestAutomation.ApiTest.dll

but the result is the same.

Code

```
public class Runner
{
    //public static string GetOutputFolder { get; } = Path.GetDirectoryName(Uri.UnescapeDataString(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath));

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Get an interface to the engine
        ITestEngine engine = TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance();

        // Create a simple test package - one assembly, no special settings
        
        TestPackage package = new TestPackage("C:\\YYY\\code\\apexautotests\\XXXAutoTests\\Build\\TestAutomation.ApiTest.dll");

        // Get a runner for the test package
        ITestRunner runner = engine.GetRunner(package);

        // Run all the tests in the assembly
        XmlNode testResult = runner.Run(listener: null, TestFilter.Empty);  
    }
}
```

NUnit are installed to test solution via Nuget
[image]

**UPDATE 1**

After a bit of debug, I found that NUnit search for the Nunit Console agent in:
"C:\YYY\code\XXXXautotests\XXXXAutoTests\TestAutomation.Runner\bin\agents\net40\nunit-agent.exe"

BUT NUnit Console is installed in package folder in root folder of solution:
"C:\YYY\code\XXXXautotests\XXXXAutoTests\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.15.2\tools\agents\net40"
Is there a way to specify where NUnit is installed for ITestRunenr?

After manually copy of nunit-agent.exe to folder "TestAutomation.Runner\bin\agents\net40" error message is different - now it can not found assembly 'nunit.framework'
But assembly 'nunit.framework' exists and it is not clear where ITestRunner is searching for it :(

```
NUnitEngineException : An exception occurred in the driver while loading tests.
  ----> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=3.13.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.--NUnitEngineException
An exception occurred in the driver while loading tests.

Server stack trace: 
   at NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.LoadDriver(IFrameworkDriver driver, String testFile, TestPackage subPackage)
   at NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.LoadPackage()
   at NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.EnsurePackageIsLoaded()
   at NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.RunTests(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Engine.ITestEngineRunner.Run(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)
   at NUnit.Engine.Runners.ProcessRunner.RunTests(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)
--
FileNotFoundException
Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=3.13.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   at NUnit.Engine.Drivers.NUnit3FrameworkDriver.CreateObject(String typeName, Object[] args)
   at NUnit.Engine.Drivers.NUnit3FrameworkDriver.Load(String testAssemblyPath, IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.LoadDriver(IFrameworkDriver driver, String testFile, TestPackage subPackage)
```

**UPDATE 2**
problems solved

Problem 1.  nunit-agent.exe shall be in the 'bin' folder of project where you write your Runner

Nunit tries to find agent in
C:\YYY\code\XXXXautotests\XXXXAutoTests\TestAutomation.Runner\bin\agents\net40\nunit-agent.exe

Real agent location nunit-agent.exe from \packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.15.2\tools\agents\net40
C:\YYY\code\XXXXautotests\XXXXAutoTests\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.15.2\tools\agents\net40

Solution: copy from \packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.15.2\tools\agents\net40 to TestAutomation.Runner\bin\agents\net40\nunit-agent.exe

Problem 2. I specified a wrong place with test dlls. Take dlls that are in Build folder not in project folder
// Get an interface to the engine
ITestEngine engine = TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance();

// Create a simple test package - one assembly, no special settings
// Note - take dlls that are in Build folder not in project folder
TestPackage package = new TestPackage("C:\YYY\code\XXXXautotests\XXXXAutoTests\Build\TestAutomation.ApiTest.dll");

// Get a runner for the test package
ITestRunner runner = engine.GetRunner(package);

// Run all the tests in the assembly
XmlNode testResult = runner.Run(listener: null, TestFilter.Empty);

Comment: The specific error indicates that something is wrong with your installation and the engine cannot find an agent to run. But you haven't given enough info to provide a real answer. What version of the engine are you using? Where did you get it and how did you install it? Show your code, which calls the engine.

Comment: @Charlie I've updated the original post

Comment: @igor as it seems that your last update solves the issue, would you mind posting that text as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)? It's the recommended procedure, because it highlights to users browsing questions that this problem does have a solution. I recommend editing the question text to remove everything after "UPDATE 2" and simply move that to an answer, which you can self-accept. If you can, please also try to use appropriate markdown to format your text.